# Is there a way to export query editor query results to a file?

Tags: soql, developer-console, query-editor

Is there a way to export query results from the query editor in the developer console to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, but if you download Data Loader (`Setup` > `Administer` > `Data Management` > `Data Loader`) you can initialize an `Export` operation and then paste in your `SOQL`.

Answer (score 2):

Besides @AdrianLarson answer, you can also use Workbench. Be sure to click the Bulk CSV radio button

[image]

[image]

Comment: A small caveat, this tool is not good for executing relationship based queries.

Comment: @abhi -- good point